# how to profile hadoop tasks with yourkit

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, yourkit

I'm trying to profile the memory usage of my hadoop job.

Could someone provide a step by step how-to on how to monitor hadoop tasks with yourkit - including setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add the following entry to your mapred-site.xml file(which if found in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/, where $HADOOP_HOME is your Hadoop installation directory):

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>
 -agentpath:{yourkit installation directory}/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=tracing,dir={output directory}
 </value>
</property>
```

If you are running on a platform different from linux-x86-64, you might need to change above value to match your platform(see [this](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/agent.jsp) for details)

You can pass any of the options listed [here](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/startup_options.jsp) to the profiler agent

This will create a number of snapshots, one for each Child process in the specified output directory